# Assets not copied from project to dist folder in Angular 7 library

Tags: angular, npm, angular7

i've generated new library via Angular CLI v7

```
ng generate library library-name
```

After that, i've created folder assets in src folder. So my folder structure is

```
| - src
| - - lib
| - - - assets
```

My problem is, that after

```
ng build --project=library-name
```

are assets missing in my dist folder. All modules, components, styles etc. are exported in dist folder. But if i create another directory in this hierarchy, directory is not exported to dist at all.

How can i force assets to be exported in dist folder after build ?

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not currently supported by the CLI, you can read more in the GitHub issue here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11071#issuecomment-395096971

An easy workaround as suggested is to manually `cp -r path/to/lib/assets list/path/to/lib` the assets after you build the library. You could use a post build script in your package.json for this.

Comment: Hi hippelee, thank you for reply. I will try it ASAP. Package built on dist have folders lib/ bundles/lib etc. To which lib folder I should copy it ?

Comment: It may depend on your library so you might need to try different locations. To start, I would put it in the same location (relative) in dist as it is for the library.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed since approx. Jan 2020

[src](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/copy-assets.md)

#### tldr;

in `ng-package.json` or equiv. you can include what you want bundled:

```
{
  ...,
  "assets": [
    "./assets",
    "CHANGELOG.md",
    "./styles/**/*.theme.scss"
  ],
  ...
}
```

#### main project glob

You'll also want to be sure to include the glob in your angular.json that's importing the packaged lib.

condensed example:

```
"projects": { "hello-world": {
    "projectType": "application",
    "architect": { "build": { "options": {
      "assets": [
        ...,
        {
          "glob": "**/*",
          "input": "node_modules/your/library",
          "output": "./assets"
        }
      ]
} } } } }
```